# How to copy list of public S3 files to private S3 bucket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-s3

In rails, and with (say 5k files) using the `aws-sdk` gem, what is the easiest way to copy a list of public files that are hosted on S3 (not my account) into my private bucket? I would want to keep the same file and path name.

Example:

`http://target.com.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/videos/abc123.mp4  (public)`

`http://myexample.com.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/videos/abc123.mp4 (private)`

I would like read the files into memory and directly stream into S3. I won't have disk space with my hosting provider (Heroku). These files are MP4s and are about 3-4MB in size.

Here's my approach (UNTESTED):

```
vid_file = 'http://example.com.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/videos/abc123.mp4'
vid_response = HTTParty.get(vid_file)

if vid_response.code == 200

  filename = File.basename(vid_file) # TOOD - fix to include s3 folder before object filename

  s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: ENV['AWS_REGION'])
  obj = s3.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET']).object(filename)
  obj.put(body: vid_response.body)
end
```

However, is the a way with the SDK to direct AWS to perform an internal copy between the S3 bucket, albeit I don't have the keys for the first bucket (but the objects are public)? If NOT, is my above approach correct (streaming into memory, posting to S3)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) There's is no sdk feature for an 'internal copy' of public S3 objects to ones private S3 bucket.

2) the below source works, which keeps the same S3 directory structure

```
vid_file = 'http://example.com.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/videos/abc123.mp4'
vid_response = HTTParty.get(vid_file)

if vid_response.code == 200

  uri_path = URI(vid_url).path 
  uri_path.slice!(0) # slice!(0) removes leading slash, otherwise creates an empty s3 folder

  s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: ENV['AWS_REGION'])
  obj = s3.bucket(ENV['S3_BUCKET']).object(uri_path)
  obj.put(body: vid_response.body) if !obj.exists?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution if you know the file name pattern is to use something like wget and then a ruby s3 client to upload to your private bucket. I understand why you would want to use memory instead of hdd but honestly assuming you have a couple gigs free your internet connection is probably the bottleneck.

Comment: I updated my question. Take a look - let me know your thoughts.